# pry -r ./config/environment different from pry -r config/environment

Tags: linux, pry

When one is in the rails - application folder, why is it different

```
$demo_app> pry -r ./config/environment
```

from

```
$demo_app> pry -r config/environment
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

./ means current folder where you are executing the command, if ./ is not mentioned it will also try to find in the class path